# Android app in three languages

Tags: android, localization

I wanna create my android app in three languages. English & Punjabi & Gujarai.

"Gujarati" & "Punjabi" is not available in locale list of languages. so i can't able to create values folder like values-fr(french) and value-rs(russia).. like dat.. How can i develop this app with "Punjabi" & "Gujarati"?

Thanks & Regards,
Jay Patel

Comment: @RahulMatte : Kindly refer acceptable answer! I have done using that font file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gujarati fonts](http://saumil.net/howto/gujfont/gujfont.html)

[Punjabi fonts](http://font.downloadatoz.com/font,2315,punjabi.html)

The above links has fonts for Gujarati and Punjabi language 
and u need to add this in assets folder and u need to use TypeFace 
class to set that font

Answer (score 1):

see list of supported locale from following Url 
http://www.science.co.il/language/locale-codes.asp

U can support Gujarati just add gu-rIN folder in values folder.

Comment: Thanks to u too.. this is also nice solution.

Comment: One question here dude.. I have to write values folder like "values-gu" ??

Comment: i have to put "gu-rIN" folder in values folder? n in "gu-rIN" folder i have to put strings.xml??

Comment: yes actually add gu-rIN folder. I means language is gujrati and region is India

Answer (score 0):

If Android doesn't offer the language choices, you'll have to implement your own language toolkits: a translation framework and a menu where a user can change the language.